#  \CatchFileDef vs ( \input or \@@input )

Tags: programming

I discovered catchfile [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48649/tikz-read-out-file)  and now I would like to understand how works this package.
Below some tests with `\foreach` or `\@for`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents,catchfile,pgffor}

\begin{document}

\def\mylist{1,2,3,4} 
Test 1:\foreach \i in \mylist {\hspace{\i cm}\i} 

\begin{filecontents*}{mylist.dat}
1,2,3,4
\end{filecontents*}

\CatchFileDef{\tempa}{mylist.dat}{}% 

Test 2:\foreach \i in \tempa{\hspace{\i cm}\i} 

\makeatletter 

Test 3:\@for\i:=\tempa\do{\hspace{\i cm}\i}

\def\tempb{\@@input mylist.dat } 

% I know this is not the right way but I always find it difficult to explain


Test 4: this is the content : \tempb  
% \foreach \i in \tempb 
% {\hspace{\i cm}\i}    %  

Test 5:\@for\i:=\tempb\do{\hspace{\i cm}\i} 

\begin{filecontents*}{myfile.dat}
\def\tempc{1,2,3,4}
\end{filecontents*}  
\input{myfile.dat}

% last try ! and it works
Test 6:\foreach \i in \tempc{\hspace{\i cm}\i}   

\end{document}
```

A) Test 4 does not work. but why Test 2 with `\CatchFileDef` works ? It would be interesting to have a clean explanation about this kind of problem !

B) Now why Test 6 works ?

Comment: I would rather check the source code of this package instead to understand how it works. AFAIK, you need some e-TeX trickery like `\everyeof{\noexpand}` or similar to avoid an error triggered by the end of the file. The package however also allows for catcode adjustments for the input file, IIRC.

Comment: The result of Test 5 is strange but the test compiles with `\def\tempb{\input{mylist.dat}}` but I got an error directly with `\edef\tempb{\input{mylist.dat}}`. I need to write `\expandafter\def\expandafter\tempb{\input{mylist.dat}}` but in this  case the test 5 does not compile

Comment: You're missing the fact that `\CatchFileDef` has *three* arguments.

Comment: yes I compile with `\CatchFileDef{\tempa}{mylist.dat}{}` but I forgot why I removed `{}` .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `\CatchFileEdef` might be simplified into

```
\newcommand\easyCatchFileEdef[3]{%
   \begingroup\everyeof{\noexpand}%
   #3\relax
   \xdef\@temp{\@@input #2\space}%
   \endgroup
   \let#1\@temp
}
```

but Heiko Oberdiek adds to this many checks. The `\everyeof{\noexpand}` is necessary to neutralize the implicit empty line that TeX adds to every file it inputs. The `\@@input` command is the primitive `\input`, which is expandable (with null expansion); the final `\space` is there for coping with the conventions of TeX regarding `\input` (primitive): a space is looked for and ignored. The third argument is used to add settings when inputting the file, for instance to `\endlinedchar`.

With `\xdef` everything is expanded (it's `\global\edef`), but then `#1` is defined only locally.

More complicated is `\CatchFileDef`, because one wants to expand only `\@@input` and not what is actually input. The unabridged version is

```
\makeatletter
\def\easyCatchFileDef#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup\everyeof\expandafter{\CatchFileEOF\expandafter\CatchFileFinish\noexpand}%
  \expandafter\long\expandafter\def\expandafter\CatchFileDo
    \expandafter##\expandafter1\CatchFileEOF{\edef\CatchFileFinish{\endgroup
      \unexpanded{\edef#1{\unexpanded{##1}}}}}%
  #3\relax
  \expandafter\CatchFileDo\@@input #2\relax}
\begingroup
  \lccode65=64 % lowercase('A') = '@'
  \lccode66=64 % lowercase('B') = '@'
  \catcode65=8 % catcode('A') = subscript
  \catcode66=3 % catcode('B') = math shift
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \def\CatchFileEOF{AB}%
}
\makeatother
```

The tokens `\CatchFileEOF` are two `@`, the first with catcode 8 and the second with catcode 3 (that nobody is supposed to have in a file) and, essentially, what is executed with `\easyCatchFiledef{\my}{file}{}` is

```
\def\CatchFileDo#1@@{%
  \edef\CatchFileFinish{\endgroup
    \unexpanded{\edef\my{\unexpanded{#1}}}}}%
\CatchFileDo<contents of file.tex>@@\CatchFileFinish
```

because the `\expandafter` before `\CatchfileDo` will expand `\@@input` and present TeX with the contents of `file.tex`. In the lines above `@@` represent the `\CatchFileEOF` special delimiter tokens.

Actually `catchfile.sty` contains code for the case when `\unexpanded` is not what is in the present version of e-TeX, but this is irrelevant for the discussion. A clever job by Heiko, as usual.

Answer (score 6):

The `\CatchFileDef` macro works AFAIK with some e-TeX trickery. Without that you get an error if you use TeX's `\input` (renamed to `\@@input` within LaTeX) inside an expandable context like `\edef`. In this case an error like "End of file detected while ..." is triggered.

Your test 4 doesn't work because you are using `\@@input` in a simple `\def` here:

```
\def\tempb{\@@input mylist.dat } 
\foreach \i in \tempb {..}
```

Note that `\tempb` does *not* contain the content of the file but rather the `\@@input` macro with the filename, which is not good for `\foreach`.
It's like using `\foreach \i in {\@@input mylist.dat} {..}`, which doesn't make much sense.
You would need to use `\edef` instead to expand the `\@@input` before so that `\tempb` does contain the file content first. However, this does not work as mentioned above.

Test 6 works as because you define the macro `\tempc` with the comma-separated content directly, just inside an input-file, which doesn't make any difference here. Does test 5 work for you? It would be more surprising for me.

Comment: I try to read the source code of catchfile.sty but it's not easy to understand.

Comment: The e-TeX trick used is `\everyeof`.