# Applying TikZ options stored in a file

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files

I need to set some TikZ options that have been written to a file by a script.

I thought I could use a helper macro defined with `\edef` and the expandable version of `\input` as described in [Why is \input not expandable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43006/why-is-input-not-expandable), but the compilation of my minimal document fails with

```
Runaway definition?
->\tikzset { every node/.style={ fill=orange!50,draw=black,thick
! File ended while scanning definition of \auxmacro.
<inserted text>
}
l.12 \@@input inputfile.txt
```

Here's the test document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{inputfile.txt}
fill=orange!50,draw=black,thick
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\edef\auxmacro{\noexpand\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        \@@input inputfile.txt
    }
}}
\auxmacro
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {Testnode};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I apply TikZ options stored in a file?

Comment: Posibly related [catchfiledef-vs-\input-or-\@@input](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48729/catchfiledef-vs-input-or-input)

Comment: I use `\input{setTikZ}` for this. However, the content of my `setTikZ.tex`-file includes the `tikzset{}`-stuff already. Wouldn't a small adjustment to your script solve this problem?

Comment: @dhst: Ah yes, that's a nice pragmatic approach. I'd still be interested to see a way of using a file containing only the actual keys, not the `\tikset` macro.

Comment: @Jake: True. I'll put the (minimally) adjusted MWE into an answer, because of the nicer formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\everyeof` e-tex primitive is your friend:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{inputfile.txt}
fill=orange!50,draw=black,thick
\end{filecontents}

\everyeof{\relax}
\makeatletter
\def\auxmacro#1\relax{\tikzset{every node/.style={#1}}}
\expandafter\auxmacro\@@input inputfile.txt 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {Testnode};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake Be careful that no `\relax` must be in the input file, but the delimiting token can be changed. Also `\everyeof` should probably be reset.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Any tinkering with `\expandafter\auxmacro\@@input inputfile.txt` fails. For example, `\auxmacro\input inputfile.txt` doesn't make any sense, since LaTeX did `\def\input{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\@iinput\@@input}`. What is so special about `\@@input`, which is the original `\input`? (`\ifx\@@input\@undefined\let\@@input\input\fi`)

Comment: @AhmedMusa the primitive `\input` known as `\@@input` in latex is _expandable_ which has advantages and makes it amenable to being expanded with `\expandafter`. However it has a weird (and system dependent) syntax. The LaTeX version  uses normal `{...}` syntax but because it also supports the priginal syntax without braces it does an `\@ifnextchar` test which makes it _not_ expandadable.

Answer (score 5):

Including all necessary macros in the external file allows for a very straightforward approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{inputfile.tex}
    \tikzset{every node/.style={
        fill=orange!10, draw=black, thick
    }}
\end{filecontents}

\input{inputfile}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {Testnode};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't use `\@@input` in an `\edef` definition because the end-of-file triggers an error. There is the [`catchfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/catchfile) package which does this task for you by using some e-TeX features (similar to David's answer). It stores the file content in a macro which then can be used together with `/.expand once` in a `\tikzset` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{inputfile.txt}
fill=orange!50,draw=black,thick
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\CatchFileDef{\extstyles}{inputfile.txt}{}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style/.expand once=\extstyles
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {Testnode};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```