# Expandable read from file

Tags: external-files

This question follows this [Applying TikZ options stored in a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59017/applying-tikz-options-stored-in-a-file/59028#comment125137_59028). I just wonder why the following fails to read the file. Please ignore the content of filecontents; although it works, it's just for developing a MNWE. The problem is with my use of `\input`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myaux.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\chapno{1}
\def\exno{1.1}
\chardef\other=12
\newwrite\ans
\immediate\openout\ans=answers
\def\answer{%
  \par\medbreak
  \immediate\write\ans{}%
  \immediate\write\ans{\string\ansno\chapno.\exno:}%
  \copytoblankline
}
\def\copytoblankline{\begingroup\setupcopy\copyans}
\def\setupcopy{%
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=\other}%
  \dospecials
  \catcode`\|=\other
  \obeylines%
}
\def\ifnextisspace{%
  \expandafter\futurelet\expandafter\next
  \expandafter\ifn@xtisspace\string
}
\def\ifn@xtisspace{%
  \ifx\next\@sptoken\expandafter\gobblespace
    \else\expandafter\writetofile\fi
}
\@namedef{gobblespace} {\ifnextisspace}
\def\writetofile#1\@nil{\immediate\write\ans{#1}}

{\obeylines %
  \gdef\copyans#1
  {\def\next{#1}%
    \ifx\next\@empty %
      \let\next=\endgroup %
    \else %
      \expandafter\ifnextisspace\next\@nil %
      \let\next=\copyans %
    \fi %
    \next %
  }%
}

\answer xxx
yyy \ifx xx
\fi zzz

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\lccode`\A=1 \lccode`\B=1 \catcode`\A=7
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\catch@marker{AB}}
\edef\reserved@a{%
  \long\def\noexpand\catchfile##1\catch@marker{%
    \noexpand\unexpanded\noexpand\expandafter{##1}%
  }%
}
\reserved@a
\def\catchfilecontent#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \everyeof\expandafter{\catch@marker\noexpand}%
  \makeatletter
  \edef\reserved@a{\endgroup
    \long\def\noexpand#1{%
      \expandafter\catchfile\expandafter\@empty
      \@@input #2
    }%
  }%
  \reserved@a
}
\makeatother

% Test
\catchfilecontent\myauxfile{myaux.tex}

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Comment: Trying your example, I don't get any `\input`-related error, but a complaint about `Illegal parameter number in definition of \myauxfile` which is exactly the  same as if I copy the contents of `filecontents` directly into `\long\def\myauxfile{`. So the problem does seem to lie inside `filecontents`.

Comment: If I replace `#` by `##` inside `filecontents`, it works. As for the direct definition. So the file catching seems to work as expected (what else did you expect from Heiko? :)

Comment: The problem is exactly that TeX finds `#1` when scanning the replacement text for `\def\myauxfile{<contents of the file>}`. The `catchfile` package takes precautions against this, so `\CatchFileDef\myauxfile{myaux.tex}{}` works perfectly.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: Thanks. I don't how Heiko came in here. I was torture-testing a scheme I saw by David Carlisle, on the expandability of TeX's original `\input`. I will fix the 'Illegal parameter' problem.

Comment: Sorry for misattribution. The code looked very similar to Heiko's package, so I thought you had modified that. But it's also possible it went the other way round ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but I have never seen that code by Heiko. I first came across the special marker trick from Joseph Wright. The file catching part was my own attempt. BTW, it is not right to simply replace `#` by `##` anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked at the implementation of *catchfile* package, but verbatimizing `#` solves the problem. I can't yet think of another way out.

```
\def\catchfilecontent#1#2{%
  \begingroup
  \def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12}%
  \dospecials
  \catcode`\|=12
  \obeylines%
  \everyeof\expandafter{\catch@marker\noexpand}%
  \makeatletter%
  \edef\reserved@a{\endgroup%
    \long\def\noexpand#1{%
      \expandafter\catchfile\expandafter\@empty%
      \@@input #2 %
    }%
  }%
  \reserved@a%
}
```

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek uses a `\toks` register to store the file's contents, so that the `#` are doubled and the subsequent `\edef` works.

Comment: @egreg: That's why I tried `\unexpanded`, eTeX's expandable way of using `\toks`, but apparently it didn't work without verbatimizing special characters. In fact, I have also tried the `\toks` based approach.