# Definition-time expansiton of command line input

Tags: conditionals, expansion, python

I'm trying to make the following code work correctly. I'm using command line call to python to check whether a number is in a list (no clue how to do this in pure LaTeX(?)). I then want to check whether the result is 'True' or 'False'.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mysequence}{[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101]}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\isprime[1]{\@@input|"python -c print((#1)in\mysequence)"}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\compare}[1]{%
\def\test{\isprime{#1}}
\def\true{True}
\def\false{False}

Test: \test\par
\ifx\test\true
#1 is PRIME! :D
\else
#1 is not prime ;(
\fi
\vspace{10pt}
}%

\begin{document}
\compare{3} % 3 is prime
\par
\compare{4} % 4 is not prime
\end{document}
```

As is, I get a correct value of `\test`, but the `\ifx` comparison does not seem to expand the `\@@input` and I get a wrong result. The output looks like that:

[image]

I believe I could fix this by using `\edef` instead of `\def`, but we I try i make LaTeX very angry and it goes a little bit too far past my knowlegde of it to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want a solution that goes through an external program, you can get inspiration from [this answer of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16794/73317) and do:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\mysequence}{%
  [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101]%
}

\newcommand*{\isInList@i}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand}%
  \edef\x{\@@input|"python3 -c 'print(#2 in #1)'" }%
  \expandafter
  \endgroup
  \expandafter
  \ifstrequal\expandafter{\x}{True}{%
    #2 is in the list}{%
    #2 is not in the list}.%
}

\newcommand*{\isInList}[1]{%
  \expandafter\isInList@i\expandafter{\mysequence}{#1}%
}

\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,...,23} {%
  \isInList{\i}\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

(I didn't want to say “prime” here because the list contained in `\mysequence` is limited; that would lead to say, for instance, that 103 isn't a prime number...)

Note for the passersby: compiling this requires giving the `-shell-escape` option to LaTeX (`pdflatex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex`, etc.); otherwise, it will refuse  to run the shell command `python3 -c '...'` contained in the code (this security measure ensures that classes, packages and documents don't run arbitrary shell commands behind your back).

Comment: Cool! Thats quite in line with my original approach. Could you explain the `\endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand}%` line? Also, why is the chain of `\noexpand`s starting within the group. Could you not get rid of the first `\expandafter` after the `\edef`?

Comment: `\m@ne` is a shorthand for `-1 ` defined in plain.tex (`\countdef\m@ne=22 \m@ne=-1`). It is faster and has lighter memory usage than typing `-1 ` directly. So, the first thing is identical to `\endlinechar=-1 \everyeof{\noexpand}`. This part is rather tricky. I got it from [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16794/73317) and you can find some explanations [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48819/73317) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117907/73317) (the latter about `\scantokens`, but it's all closely related). Basically, newline characters from the input...

Comment: ... (here, from the *output* of the shell command which becomes input for TeX) are turned into the character with code given by `\endlinechar`, unless this is negative or greater than 255 (TeXbook p. 48). If you play with `\endlinechar=67 % TeX's internal code for C` and `\edef\x{\@@input|"python3 -c 'print(chr(10), chr(65), chr(10), chr(66))'" }`, you should see `Runaway definition?
->CACBC
! File ended while scanning definition of \x.` The end-of-line produced by Python (`chr(10)`) got turned into `C`. But it seems vey tricky to get this working without errors when `\endlinechar`...

Comment: ... is between 0 and 255. The rest is easier to explain (all from me). The chain of `\expandafter`s starting inside the group expands `\x` while its definition is still active (`\endgroup` hasn't gotten into TeX's stomach yet, i.e. hasn't been “executed”), so that the first argument of `\ifstrequal` will be exactly the output of the shell command when TeX later expands `\ifstrequal`. Then the `\expandafter`s disappear (they have been expanded), `\endgroup` becomes the next token to process by TeX. As it is unexpandable, it gets executed, which ends the group and restores `\x` to the status...

Comment: ... it had before `\begingroup`. So, these `\expandafter`s ensure that everything is quite clean after the `\endgroup` has been digested by TeX. If you remove the first `\expandafter` after the `\edef`, `\endgroup` will be executed before TeX got any chance to expand the `\x` in the first argument of `\ifstrequal`. So, when `\ifstrequal` is expanded, its first argument will be the control sequence token `\x` (which is not what you want; moreover, the definition of `\x` from the `\edef` will already be lost since `\endgroup` was digested earlier in this scenario).

Comment: I see! So the `\endlinechar=\m@ne` and `\everyeof{\noexpand}` are actually two different commands (which I mistakedly read as one). Quoting from [the seccond link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48729/catchfiledef-vs-input-or-input/48819#48819) you provided, `\everyeof{\noexpand}` _"is necessary to neutralize the implicit empty line that TeX adds to every file it inputs"_.

Comment: Yes, two different commands. As for the “implicit empty line”, I wonder if it is a typo for “end-of-file (EOF) marker” as mentioned in the [other link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117907/73317) (about `\scantokens`). That would make more sense to me, but I can't claim I'm sure about this. You can also read about the conditions in which `\everyeof`is called (again for `\scantokens`) at the end of the *Input Handling* section in the [e-TeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/etex) manual (use `texdoc etex` if your distribution supports this).

Answer (score 2):

Set up to use the OP's syntax for `\mysequence`, though I think space separated has certain advantages over comma separated, were I to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand{\mysequence}{[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101]}
\newcommand\compare[1]{%
  \setsepchar{,#1,||[#1,||,#1]}%
  \readlist\mylist{\mysequence}%
  \ifnum\listlen\mylist[]>1 #1 is PRIME!\else #1 is not prime\fi
}

\begin{document}

\compare{2}

\compare{3} % 3 is prime

\compare{4} % 4 is not prime

\compare{101}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

To handle the case where the argument can also be macro (e.g., `\thepage`, at least in the arabic case) that fully expands to an integer, try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand{\mysequence}{[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101]}
\newcommand\compare[1]{\edef\tmp{#1}\expandafter\compareaux\expandafter{\tmp}}
\newcommand\compareaux[1]{%
  \setsepchar{,#1,||[#1,||,#1]}%
  \readlist\mylist{\mysequence}%
  \ifnum\listlen\mylist[]>1 #1 is PRIME!\else #1 is not prime\fi
}

\begin{document}

\compare{2}

\compare{3} % 3 is prime

\compare{4} % 4 is not prime

\compare{101}

\compare{\thepage}
\end{document}
```

If one did not want to rely on `\edef`, but was satisfied to limit the macro to a single expansion, one could instead define

```
\newcommand\compare[1]{\expandafter\compareaux\expandafter{#1}}
```

Comment: This is *significanlty* simpler... It does not work, however, when I try to `\compare{\thepage}` (?). I realise its probably something to do with a completly different part of latex which I also don't understand.

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk That is because `\thepage` does not contain a number, but a command: `\csname @arabic\endcsname \c@page`.  You need to do two extra things: 1) fully expand `\thepage` as in `\edef\tmp{\thepage}` and 2) Provide the number, not the macro to `\compare`, as in `\expandafter\compare\expandafter{\tmp}`.

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk Please see my **SUPPLEMENT**.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you! I dont undertand the use of `\expandafter\command\expandafter{\argument}`, but I guess I'll go back to the [\expandafter tutorial](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf) again. :)

Comment: I was hesitant to accept the answer, as it technically circumvents the probelm rather than solving it. I feel, however, that it would be plainly unfair after an excellent answer and very much on-topic discussion of expansion.

Comment: `\expandafter\command\expandafter{\argument}` executes the initial `\expandafter`, which, by definition, skips over the `\command` and executes the next thing, which is another `\expandafter`.  That 2nd `\expandafter` skips over the left brace and expands exactly once the value of `\argument`, which means it places the literal value of `\argument` in its place.  Then what is left?  `\command{<a literal number>}`